# mayavi mlab get current axes

Tags: python, mayavi

Is there a way of a procedure similar to `plt.gca()` to get a handle to the current axes. I first do `a=mlab.surf(x, y, u2,warp_scale='auto')`

and then

`b=mlab.plot3d(yy, yy, (yy-40)**2 ,tube_radius=20.0)`

but the origin of `a` and `b` are different and the plot looks incorrect. So I want to put `b` into the axes of `a`

In short, what would be the best way in mayavi to draw a surface and a line on same axes?

Answer (score 1):

What you are expecting to be able to do from your matplotlib experience is not how mayavi axes work.  In matplotlib the visualization is a child of the axes and the axes determines its coordinates.  In mayavi or vtk, visualization sources consist of points in space.  Axes are objects that surround a source and provide tick markings of the coordinate extent of those objects, that are not necessary for the visualizations, and where they exist they are children of sources.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the argument warp_scale='auto'

```
a=mlab.surf(x, y, u2)
```

and it will work.